# Adjusting the framerate with the `animate` package

Tags: viewers, animations, animate, adobe

I am using the `animate` package to produce a slide deck with beamer and having issues adjusting the framerate.  I have experienced the following issues and I suspect that the problem lies with Adobe Reader but I'd like to know if anyone has experienced anything similar:

- If the pdf slide deck is the only pdf file open in Adobe Reader, then the framerate is slower than what I specified in the source file.
- If I have another pdf file open, and then I open my slide deck, then the framerate is correct, unless I put the slides in fullscreen mode.
- If I disable `Use 2d graphics acceleration` in Adobe Reader, then regardless of anything else, the framerate is slower than what I specified in the source file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: animations in adobe reader can not be expected to hold the frame rate, especially not if the frames are very complicated. Typically you can make it go a few times (making the animation go to the cache) and it will speed up. I know, not ideal, however, it can work.

Comment: This is not really to do with TeX: it's a 'feature' of PDFs. AS such, it's outside of our scope, sorry.