# Exporting a timed presentation (automatic slideshow) to image sequence (video) with fixed frame rate?

Tags: beamer, animate, media9

I may be beating a dead horse here; but I hope I'll be forgiven, as I have at least a Latex MWE, and some notes about packages `:)`. The thing is this: for a long time I've been looking for some sort of a platform, where I could write a text script, for what would eventually become a video edit ([Command-line video editing in Linux (cut, join and preview) - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/358082/command-line-video-editing-in-linux-cut-join-and-preview)); and I think Latex/PDF has the potential.

Unlike in [Adjusting the framerate with the `animate` package [closed]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72714/adjusting-the-framerate-with-the-animate-package), however, I wouldn't intend to use Adobe Reader as a viewer/player. Instead, I'm interested in, basically, considering the Latex or PDF format as a "container" for a timed presentation, which includes videos - and what I'd need is a script or program which would "parse" the container, and eventually generate an image sequence at a predetermined frames-per-second rate. This is maybe best discussed through an example; so with the below MWE - which uses `beamer`, `animate` and `media9` - and screen capturing the Adobe Reader full-screen performance, I obtain this animated .gif (*a longer MWE with comments is on https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e6b7051cf270594d2b38, along with a full-size video on https://vid.me/QZrL (from where you can also download a .mp4 version, JavaScript required)*):

[image: test-presentation.gif]

I think it is clear that Adobe Reader cannot be expected to hold a video-tight frame rate (especially since e.g. `{animation}` uses JavaScript timers inside the PDF to do the animating; and especially not in older Linuces like Ubuntu 11.04, where I did the screen capture). That is why I'd hope for a tool, which would preserve these attributes of the video above:

- Slide (frame) duration
- Transition effect and duration
- Animations
- Frame-accurate display of embedded videos.

With this, I could export a "base video" which I could load in a video editor; and then possibly overlay the original embedded videos over that in the editor, and then export a "final video". Firstly, I would imagine a tool that would parse the PDF, and export an image sequence like in this shell pseudocode:

```
mockPdfRender --framerate 24 --in test.pdf --out imgseq/%05d.png
```

However, that tool would need to "know" that from e.g. this 5-page PDF should be rendered into 1.5+1.5+2.5+5.5+1.5 = 12.5 seconds; @ 24 fps = 300 images; and since many of these facilities depend on embedded JavaScript, I'd imagine it would be hard. On the other hand, maybe it would be more possible, if a change was implemented in `{beamer}`, `{animate}` and `{media9}`, such that I could write a directive in my Latex file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mockPfdRender[framerate=24]{} % the directive
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{animate}
...
```

... which, when encountered, would instruct Latex to export a PDF, not with 5 pages, but with 300 pages, each containing a frame of the animation. On such a PDF, I could simply use ImageMagick's `convert`:

```
convert -density 100 test.pdf test-%05d.png
```

... to generate a `.png` image from each page of that PDF; giving me a frame-accurate image sequence that I could then import into a video editor (or `ffmpeg`), and generate a video out of it.

So, formally, my question would be: is there a facility allowing something like this in the Latex packages? If not, would it be at all possible to implement - so it works on the MWE (i.e., across `beamer`, `animate` and `media9`)? Also, some subquestions:

- How can I understand the positioning of animation and media on `{beamer}` slides?
- In `{media9}`, is there a way to start a video at a given time, and stop it a later time, automatically when the slide (page) with the video is opened?
- In [Inject JavaScript with pdflatex etc. for page level events](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122092/inject-javascript-with-pdflatex), `\pdfpageattr{/AA << /O << /S/JavaScript ...` is used to set up a JS listener when all/any page of the PDF is opened; is there a way to limit that to a single page (apart from writing a JS `if(..){..}` clause)
- Is there any way to make `{media9}` work with `annotRM.callAs()` JS command (see below)?

Aside from that, here are some notes re: the MWE on my platform:

- As per [Did anyone succeed in playing embedded movies inside Acrobat in Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed), I had to use Adobe Reader 9.4.1 to play video in PDF; apparently that version included an embedded Flash Player 9, which was subsequently removed (and later `acroread`s apparently require a standalone Flash Player to be installed on the system)
- `\movie` from package `{multimedia}` didn't work at all; had to use `\includemedia` from `{media9}`
- with `\includemedia`, using `VPlayer.swf` didn't work at all; had to use `VPlayer9.swf` (apparently because of the embedded Flash Player 9)
- `\includemedia` movie with sound caused `acroread` 9.4.1 to freeze (waiting for `pthread_join()`) upon exiting the slide, unless I had specified my default card in ALSA's `~/.asoundrc`:

  ```
  pcm.!default {
    type hw   #must have type
    card 0    #must have, else "card is not defined"
  }
  ```

  With this spec, `acroread` will survive one entry and exit in the slide playing the video, but will freeze upon second return to the slide and playback of video. Upon freeze, graceful shutdown of `acroread` is impossible, `killall -9 acroread` is required
- Only `{beamer}`'s `\transdissolve` worked as a transition inside `acroread` 9.4.1; others like `\transsplitverticalout` or `\transwipe` didn't
- `callAS` JS commands addressing `{media9}` videos (like `annotRM['myvideo'].callAS('play')`) fail silently in `acroread` 9.4.1 - and break all subsequent JS commands in that handler; because of that, `{hyperref}`'s `\PushButton` can not be used to target videos
- The only thing that can target a `{media9}`'s `\includemedia` video, is `{media9}`'s `\mediabutton` with `[mediacommand=myvideo:seek [(32.1)],]` argument - this doesn't just include JavaScript, it includes actual PDF literals like `/CMD << /C (seek) /A [(32.1)] >> /S /RichMediaExecute`
- However, `\mediabutton` does not render in `acroread` 9.4.1 in full-screen mode (see my screen capture above, where I click an empty space next to the "Test" button to seek in the video)

Other references:

- [Animations in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152358/animations-in-latex)
- [Exporting animation created with animate package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136666/exporting-animation)
- [Converting beamer slides to animated images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23727/converting-beamer-slides)
- [How can I set a time between slides to create an automatic slideshow with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40332/how-can-i-set-a-time-between)
- [Rotating a one-page float for pdf viewing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149804/rotating-a-one-page-float)

Well, that was it - here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% \usepackage{multimedia} % \movie
\usepackage{media9}[2013/11/04] % ‘media9’ package replaces the now obsolete ‘movie15’ package.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

% make as "plain Latex" style/theme for Beamer as possible

\usetheme{default}                      % empty
\usefonttheme{serif}                    % computer modern font
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}    % reset colors
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols

% centered frame title
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{ % changes all \frametitle
  \begin{centering}
  \insertframetitle
  \par
  \end{centering}
}

\def\choicetransition{\transdissolve[duration=0.5]}

\begin{document}

\title{Testing a timed presentation, with animation and video}
\author{My Author}
\date{2015}

% slide 01
\frame{ \choicetransition \transduration{1.5} %
\titlepage %
}

  % this executes on opening all subsequent pages; but...
  \pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr /AA <<
    /O << /S/JavaScript /JS (
    if (this.pageNum==3) {
      ret = annotRM['myvideo'].callAS('play'); % ... does not work
    }
  ) >>
  >>}

% slide 02
\begin{frame}[plain] \choicetransition \transduration{1.5} %
  \begin{center}%
  \Large
  Hello there\\[1em]

  Just trying a plain old frame out
  \end{center}%
\end{frame}

% slide 03: animation
\begin{frame} \choicetransition \transduration{2.5} %
  \frametitle{Testing an animation}
  % last argument of animateinline is frame rate
  \begin{animateinline}[controls=false,autoplay,loop=false]{4}
  \multiframe{8}{n=-0.4+0.1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10,rotate=90]
      \draw[blue,opacity=0.5] (-.1,-.2) rectangle (.4,0.2);
      \draw[red] (-.1,-.2) -- (-.3,\n);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

% slide 04: video
% wget http://archive.org/download/Elephants_Dream_teaser_2/elephantsdream_teaser.ogv
% ffmpeg -i elephantsdream_teaser.ogv -acodec pcm_s16le -r 24 -g 24 elephantsdream_teaser.flv % Format: Flash Video, Video: Sorenson Spark, Audio: PCM

\begin{frame} \choicetransition \transduration{5.5} %
  \frametitle{Testing a video}

  %\movie[width=3cm,height=2cm,poster,autostart,start=5s,duration=2s,once]{}{elephantsdream_teaser.flv} % nowork, even w/ acroread 9.4.1 {multimedia}
  \includemedia[            % {media9}
    label=myvideo,          % defines JavaScript object annotRM['myvideo']
    width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.6\linewidth,
    activate=pagevisible,
    deactivate=pageinvisible,
    transparent,
    addresource=elephantsdream_teaser.flv,
    flashvars={
      source=elephantsdream_teaser.flv % same path as in addresource!
      &autoPlay=true %
      &loop=false          % loop video
      &scaleMode=letterbox % preserve aspect ratio
    }
  ]{}{VPlayer9.swf} %VPlayer.swf doesn't show video at all! Not even a frame - just white background!
  \PushButton[  %requires package ‘hyperref’
    name=thibut,
    onclick={
      console.show();
      console.println('-------------');
      console.println(annotRM.myvideo);
      console.println(annotRM['myvideo']); % object AnnotRichMedia
    },
    format={  % thought it runs at start, but it doesn't
      console.show();
      console.println('-------------');
    },
  ]{\fbox{Test}}
  \mediabutton[%
    mediacommand=myvideo:seek [(32.1)],% ok
    %jsaction=myvideo:{app.alert("Test " + typeof(annotRM['myvideo']));} % works, prints 'object'
  ]{\color{blue}\fbox{SEEK}} % works, but is invisible in acroread 9.4.1 (and visible in evince?)?
\end{frame}

% slide 05: end

\begin{frame}[plain] \choicetransition \transduration{1.5} %
  \begin{center}%
  \LARGE
  Fin
  \end{center}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```