# Adding caption at the bottom border of a page

Tags: beamer, metadata

Per title says, I'm looking for a way to place a small string at the bottom of my slides, preferably next to the slide numbers.

I'll be sending someone a rehearsal of a presentation that I'll be giving shortly. Since recording the screen results into big sized output, I'm considering to send the person slides with an audio of the presentation. So by putting a particular time value (ex. 02:33) next to each slide number, I'm aiming to signal when to jump to the upcoming slide.

Of course if there is some other way of merging the beamer output with the audio file that I'm not aware of, I would be willing to give a go at that as well.

Edit: MWE added.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{comment}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{centered page number}
{
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}
  \insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage
  \hspace*{\fill}\vskip2pt
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[centered page number]

\begin{document}

  \frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It is impossible to answer your question as it stands since the default theme doesn't even include slide numbers.

Comment: @cfr Apologies, MWE added.

Comment: Related: [Exporting a timed presentation (automatic slideshow) to image sequence (video) with fixed frame rate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225069/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to record the audio associated with the presentation and note the duration of each slide. For example,

- Slide 1: 0:05
- Slide 2: 0:07
- Slide 3: 0:12
- Slide 4: 0:04
- Slide 5: 1:00
- Slide 6: 0:10
- ...

Then, once you're comfortable with these transition times, fix them in your presentation using [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s `\transduration<<overlay spec>>{<duration in seconds>}`. As an illustration, the example below will show the first and third slide for only 1 second each, while the second slide will have 3 seconds of screen time:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usetheme{warsaw}%
\setbeamercovered{transparent}% Allow for shaded (transparent) covered items
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \transduration{1}% All slides show for 1 second
  \transduration<2>{3}% Slide 2 shows for 3 seconds

  \frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
  \framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number.
      \item<2-> Let $q$ be the \alt<3>{\alert{product}}{product} of the \uncover<3->{first} $p$ numbers.
      \item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them.
      \item<1-> But $q + 1$ is \visible<2->{greater than} $1$, thus divisible by some prime
        number not in the first $p$ numbers.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `\transduration`s only take effect when the presentation is viewed in full screen (and may be dependent on your viewer).